# How to set the keyboard position when forcing horizontal orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I wanted to force horizontal orientation of UIWebView and I could do by the following code.

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.height, frame.size.width);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 90 / 180.0f);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 70, 70);
webView.transform = transform;
```

However I can't set the position of keyboard when viewing forced orientation change view. It still views up from the bottom like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWbn5.png).
How do I set the keyboard position?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard uses statusBar orientation. I see two ways of solving your problem:
1. Set statusBar orientation to landscape ([UIApplication Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and correct your view frame.
2. Let the app to rotate your viewController. Make the app to support both portrait and landscape orientations and implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of your viewController

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I can do that using the following code.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];`